# What is the Difference Between Hammock and Hammock.ClientProfile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, hammock

I am attempting to use Hammock as a library to enable easy access to a REST API.

When I add the package using nuget in Visual Studio 2010, it adds 2 references:

- Hammock
- Hammock.ClientProfile

However, when I attempt to use the hammock classes and methods, it tells me there are duplicate implementations of certain classes.  Further, using full namespace scoping does not seem to help.

Is it possible that one should be using only Hammock -or- Hammock.ClientProfile - but never both at the same time?

If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the the creator, and he stated that there is no difference between the libraries - he was at one time planning to implement a server-side library, but never followed through on it.

My personally, I am using Hammock (and *not* using Hammock.ClientProfile).